# foregroundInsidePadding error when mirgating to Gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, aapt, aapt2

I am migrating to Gradle v3 (specifically 3.1.2) and I get an error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.",
"sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Angelina\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar\\a93d35a31f498023ac08296f6b1bf65b\\res\\values\\values.xml"}],
"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:processDebugResources
error: failed linking references.
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
```

There is no `foregroundInsidePadding` inside the code or libraries or the file in values.xml. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: show us your build.gradle app level file

Comment: @Angelina did you able to resolve this because I am facing same issue

Comment: @AJay no, i decided to postpone this change

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "android:" prefix. You should use "@attr/foregroundInsidePadding", not "android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding".

Comment: There is no `foregroundInsidePadding` in that values.xml file! I searched in appcompat v7 library and found some, i deleted `android:` prefix and tried to build - no effect, still smae error :(

Comment: Can you share your project? It's possible the error is pointing to the wrong file.

Comment: sorry I cannot. How would you search? I searched inside all the dependencies through Android Studio. you have another approcah?... :/